# Value of a module reference in Terraform

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to get my api gateway deployment to redeploy when I'm making changes to it's endpoints. Each of those endpoints is defined within a module and so by following [this documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_deployment), I end up with something like the following:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "rest_api" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  
  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
      module.api_endpoint[*],
      aws_api_gateway_integration.webapp,
      aws_api_gateway_integration_response.webapp_404,
      aws_api_gateway_integration.root_redirect
    ]))
  }

  lifecycle { create_before_destroy = true }
}

module api_endpoint {
  source = "./modules/api_endpoint"

  for_each = local.paths

  api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  root_resource_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.root_resource_id
  path = each.key
  methods = each.value

  authoriser_id = aws_api_gateway_authorizer.rest_api.id
  lambda_arn = aws_lambda_function.rest_api.invoke_arn
}
```

However when I add additional api_endpoints, it's not updating. Am I missing something about the value of `module.api_endpoint[*]`? I had assumed it would work like the resources below. Do I need to make it output something that would change accordingly?

Comment: Well, I would probably use an output provided by the module as one of the redeployment triggers and see if that works.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done. I also realised that the [*] splat notation doesn't work for for_each. If you want to write that as an answer, I can accept it

Comment: Sure, but I have no idea what the outputs are, so I will take a wild guess. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the splat expression does not work when using `for_each`. Alternatively, the [`values` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values) could be used to fetch all the values for a certain output that the module provides. The other option would be to reference a single output for one of the keys. The code would look something like:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "rest_api" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  
  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
      values(module.api_endpoint)[*].<name_of_the_output>,
      aws_api_gateway_integration.webapp,
      aws_api_gateway_integration_response.webapp_404,
      aws_api_gateway_integration.root_redirect
    ]))
  }

  lifecycle { create_before_destroy = true }
}
```

where the `<name_of_the_output>` is a placeholder which should be replaced with a real output name defined in the module.